# How do you make a haptic play on the apple watch using Objective-C code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, haptic-feedback

How do you make a haptic play on the apple watch when you press a button using Objective-C and Xcode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Objective-C:**

```
[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] playHaptic:WKHapticType.Success]
```

**Swift:**

```
WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Success)
```

**Types of Haptic you can play:**

```
WKHapticType.Notification,
WKHapticType.DirectionUp,
WKHapticType.DirectionDown,
WKHapticType.Success,
WKHapticType.Failure,
WKHapticType.Retry,
WKHapticType.Start,
WKHapticType.Stop,
WKHapticType.Click
```

**Documentation:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceDevice_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceDevice

Answer (score 3):

at least in Xcode 11 in objective-c you'd do (Xcode 11)

```
 [[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] playHaptic: WKHapticTypeSuccess];
```